# Converting Celsius to Fahrenheit with integer arithmetic (for an asm implementation)

Tags: assembly, x86, integer

I am wondering how I would go about doing the math for this problem. Converting a temperature in Celsius to Fahrenheit. I can do the majority of this problem but I don't understand the `9/5` in the function. I know there is going to be a remainder of 4 with a quotient of 1 what do I do with the numbers to get the right conversion?

I have done a couple of sample calculations on my calculator on how to get the `9/5` to work, but the only way I get it to work is to work with another fraction that will give me a remainder.

Here is the equation: `F = (9/5) * Celsius + 32`

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but what are you trying to achieve with your equation? To have 32 Degree Celsius converted to Fahrenheit. Your equation should be `F = 32 * 9/5` or `F = 32 * 180/100` which is `F = C * 9/5` or `F = C * 180/100`.

Comment: @kolunar I am trying to figure out how do I do the `9/5` division/multiplication part because what I assume is that Assembly doesn't put the answer in a floating point value. So how do I do the math in that for that specific part of the equation . The `Celsius + 32` is easy to figure out.

Comment: Please read the tag description. You must tell what processor type you're targeting, and what assembler. "Assembly" isn't a single language.

Comment: You multiply by 9 and divide by 5. What is the problem in that?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen There is a remainder, like I said. I don't know how to do the math for the remainder. So 9/5 is 1 remainder 4. How do I do the math  so i can use 9/5 with out a decimal?

Comment: @Programmer12432 You can't if you don't use floating points. But if you only need integers, you don't need to care about it.

Comment: @Programmer12432, my bad, should have added 32 degree for the offset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to transform the term:

```
F = (9/5) * Celsius + 32
  = ( (9 * Celsius) / 5 ) + 32
  = ( (9 * Celsius) / 5 ) + ( (32 * 5) / 5)
  = ( (9 * Celsius) / 5 ) + ( 160 / 5)
  = ( (9 * Celsius) + 160 ) / 5
```

Now, you can do the division at the end:

1. Calculate 9 * Celsius.
2. Add 160.
3. Divide by 5.
4. Use the remainder to round the result.