# Using assembly to convert the temperature from Celsius into Fahrenheit, and back again

Tags: assembly, x86, rounding, temperature

I am using the following x86 assembly instructions to convert from degrees Celsius into degrees Fahrenheit:

```
  imul dword [NINE]
  idiv dword [FIVE]
  add  eax, 32
```

For rather a lot of inputs this produces an off-by-one error:

> ```
>  1 °C produces 33 °F, but expecting 34 °F (33.8 °F)
> -1 °C produces 31 °F, but expecting 30 °F (30.2 °F)
> ```

For now, I solved the issue through [inspection of the remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334505/converting-celsius-to-fahrenheit-with-integer-arithmetic-for-an-asm-implementat/33334755?r=SearchResults&s=18%7C31.1603#33334755) from the signed division by 5 and then rounding accordingly:

```
  imul dword [NINE]
  idiv dword [FIVE]   ; -> Remainder EDX=[-4,4]
  add  eax, 32+1
  cmp  edx, 2
  jg   @f
  dec  eax
  cmp  edx, -2
  jge  @f
  dec  eax
@@:
```

I would very much prefer a branchless solution since I've heard it would be faster, generally speaking.
Additionally, how can I change the code so it returns a decimal fraction?

Answer (score 3):

## From Celsius to Fahrenheit

The straightforward implementation in x86 assembly for the conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit uses next formula:

> ```
> Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
C2F_a:  imul    dword [NINE]
        idiv    dword [FIVE]
        add     eax, 32
        ret
```

Signed operations are needed because both Celsius and Fahrenheit also exist in the negative numbers range. Their scales begin at [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) (0 K): [Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_Celsius) starts at -273.15 °C and [Fahrenheit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_scale) starts at -459.67 °F.

### Rounding

An important drawback of the above code is that the results don't get properly rounded to the **nearest** integer.  (`idiv` rounds toward zero, aka truncation.) The simplest way to achieve this kind of rounding would be to *add* 2 to the dividend prior to dividing by 5. Sadly, this only works well for positive inputs. For negative inputs, we would rather need to *subtract* 2 before dividing by 5.
Next solution therefore avoids *signed* division by first adding a suitable bias to the input. The remainder of the code no longer needs to consider negative numbers. A bias of 275 will render any legal input positive, and will not introduce a further rounding issue because the value that will eventually remove the bias is an integer: (275 * 9 / 5) = 495.

> ```
> Fahrenheit = (((Celsius + 275) * 9) + 2) / 5 + (32 - 495)
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
C2F_b:  add     eax, 275
        imul    eax, 9
        add     eax, 2
        xor     edx, edx
        div     dword [FIVE]
        add     eax, 32-495
        ret
```

### Optimization

It is possible to replace the multiplication by 9 with a `LEA` instruction that at the same time absorbs several additions.
It is equally possible to replace the division by 5 with a multiplication by 5's [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse).

> ```
> Fahrenheit = (((Celsius + 275) * 9) + 2) / 5 + (32 - 495)
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
C2F_c:  lea     eax, [eax+eax*8+(275*9)+2]
        mov     edx, 0CCCCCCCDh
        mul     edx
        shr     edx, 2
        lea     eax, [edx+32-495]
        ret
```

### Precision

Using decimal [fixed-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) with scaling 1/100, we can deliver results that are accurate to 2 decimal places. eg. -273.15 °C gets stored as the signed integer -27315, and will output the signed integer -45967 which represents -459.67 °F.

> ```
> Fahrenheit = (((Celsius + 27500) * 9) + 2) / 5 + (3200 - 49500)
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
C2F_d:  lea     eax, [eax+eax*8+(27500*9)+2]
        mov     edx, 0CCCCCCCDh
        mul     edx
        shr     edx, 2
        lea     eax, [edx+3200-49500]
        ret
```

| °C | C2F_a | C2F_b | C2F_c | C2F_d | Sharp® |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -10 | 14 | 14 | 14 | 14.00 | 14 |
| -9 | 16 | 16 | 16 | 15.80 | 15.8 |
| -8 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 17.60 | 17.6 |
| -7 | 20! | 19 | 19 | 19.40 | 19.4 |
| -6 | 22! | 21 | 21 | 21.20 | 21.2 |
| -5 | 23 | 23 | 23 | 23.00 | 23 |
| -4 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 24.80 | 24.8 |
| -3 | 27 | 27 | 27 | 26.60 | 26.6 |
| -2 | 29! | 28 | 28 | 28.40 | 28.4 |
| -1 | 31! | 30 | 30 | 30.20 | 30.2 |
| 0 | 32 | 32 | 32 | 32.00 | 32 |
| 1 | 33! | 34 | 34 | 33.80 | 33.8 |
| 2 | 35! | 36 | 36 | 35.60 | 35.6 |
| 3 | 37 | 37 | 37 | 37.40 | 37.4 |
| 4 | 39 | 39 | 39 | 39.20 | 39.2 |
| 5 | 41 | 41 | 41 | 41.00 | 41 |
| 6 | 42! | 43 | 43 | 42.80 | 42.8 |
| 7 | 44! | 45 | 45 | 44.60 | 44.6 |
| 8 | 46 | 46 | 46 | 46.40 | 46.4 |
| 9 | 48 | 48 | 48 | 48.20 | 48.2 |
| 10 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50.00 | 50 |

## From Fahrenheit to Celsius

The straightforward implementation in x86 assembly for the conversion from
Fahrenheit to Celsius uses next formula:

> ```
> Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
F2C_a:  sub     eax, 32
        imul    dword [FIVE]
        idiv    dword [NINE]
        ret
```

Signed operations are needed because both Celsius and Fahrenheit also exist in the negative numbers range. Their scales begin at [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) (0 K): [Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_Celsius) starts at -273.15 °C and [Fahrenheit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_scale) starts at -459.67 °F.

### Rounding

An important drawback of the above code is that the results don't get properly rounded to the **nearest** integer. The simplest way to achieve this kind of rounding would be to *add* 4 to the dividend prior to dividing by 9. Sadly, this only works well for positive inputs. For negative inputs, we would rather need to *subtract* 4 before dividing by 9.
Next solution therefore avoids *signed* division by first adding a suitable bias to the input. The remainder of the code no longer needs to consider negative numbers. A bias of 495 will render any legal input positive, and will not introduce a further rounding issue because the value that will eventually remove the bias is an integer: (495 * 5 / 9) = 275.

> ```
> Celsius = (((Fahrenheit + 495 - 32) * 5) + 4) / 9 - 275
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
F2C_b:  add     eax, 495-32
        imul    eax, 5
        add     eax, 4
        xor     edx, edx
        div     dword [NINE]
        sub     eax, 275
        ret
```

### Optimization

It is possible to replace the multiplication by 5 with a `LEA` instruction that at the same time absorbs several additions.
It is equally possible to replace the division by 9 with a multiplication by 9's [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse).

> ```
> Celsius = (((Fahrenheit + 495 - 32) * 5) + 4) / 9 - 275
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
F2C_c:  lea     eax, [eax+eax*4+(495-32)*5+4]
        mov     edx, 38E38E39h
        mul     edx
        shr     edx, 1
        lea     eax, [edx-275]
        ret
```

### Precision

Using decimal [fixed-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) with scaling 1/100, we can deliver results that are accurate to 2 decimal places. eg. -459.67 °F gets stored as the signed integer -45967, and will output the signed integer -27315 which represents -273.15 °C.

> ```
> Celsius = (((Fahrenheit + 49500 - 3200) * 5) + 4) / 9 - 27500
> ```

```
; IN (eax) OUT (eax) MOD (edx)
F2C_d:  lea     eax, [eax+eax*4+(49500-3200)*5+4]
        mov     edx, 38E38E39h
        mul     edx
        shr     edx, 1
        lea     eax, [edx-27500]
        ret
```

| °F | F2C_a | F2C_b | F2C_c | F2C_d | Sharp® |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -10 | -23 | -23 | -23 | -23.33 | -23.333333 |
| -9 | -22! | -23 | -23 | -22.78 | -22.777777 |
| -8 | -22 | -22 | -22 | -22.22 | -22.222222 |
| -7 | -21! | -22 | -22 | -21.67 | -21.666666 |
| -6 | -21 | -21 | -21 | -21.11 | -21.111111 |
| -5 | -20! | -21 | -21 | -20.56 | -20.555555 |
| -4 | -20 | -20 | -20 | -20.00 | -20 |
| -3 | -19 | -19 | -19 | -19.44 | -19.444444 |
| -2 | -18! | -19 | -19 | -18.89 | -18.888888 |
| -1 | -18 | -18 | -18 | -18.33 | -18.333333 |
| 0 | -17! | -18 | -18 | -17.78 | -17.777777 |
| 1 | -17 | -17 | -17 | -17.22 | -17.222222 |
| 2 | -16! | -17 | -17 | -16.67 | -16.666666 |
| 3 | -16 | -16 | -16 | -16.11 | -16.111111 |
| 4 | -15! | -16 | -16 | -15.56 | -15.555555 |
| 5 | -15 | -15 | -15 | -15.00 | -15 |
| 6 | -14 | -14 | -14 | -14.44 | -14.444444 |
| 7 | -13! | -14 | -14 | -13.89 | -13.888888 |
| 8 | -13 | -13 | -13 | -13.33 | -13.333333 |
| 9 | -12! | -13 | -13 | -12.78 | -12.777777 |
| 10 | -12 | -12 | -12 | -12.22 | -12.222222 |